# Глюк в Json Android

Tags: java, android, json

```
String line = "";
                String strJson = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("line",line);
                    Log.e("asd","ad");
                    strJson += line;
                    Log.e("json",strJson);
                }
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
                rd.close();
                commands=new String[2];
                Log.e("asd",jsonObject.toString());


E/json﹕ {"result":1,"data":{"commands":[{"ID":123,"call":123123},{"ID":1231,"blink":"true"}]}}
E/asd﹕ {"data":{"commands":[{"ID":123,"call":123123},{"blink":"true","ID":1231}]},"result":1}
```

Что это за глюк такой?

Раньше я так делал и норм было, щяс все перевернуто. Помогите решить эту проблему, это глюк такой чтоли?

Comment: Ну да, смущяет порядок. Вот именно. Это же просто строка. 1 целая строка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `JSONObject` порядок не гарантируется так-то. Если нужно сохранить порядок добавления, то используйте мэпу:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> jsonOrderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

jsonOrderedMap.put("1","one");
jsonOrderedMap.put("2","two");
jsonOrderedMap.put("3","three");

JSONObject orderedJson = new JSONObject(jsonOrderedMap);

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(orderedJson));
```